# Resetting template driven forms properly in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I often use template-driven forms in Angular and does the form reset using `resetForm()` function. But occasionally, this runs into a weird behaviour where the `resetForm()` function only resets the values and not the validation errors. I did some debugging and found that the `submitted` state is not getting reset.

**Sample form :**

```html
<form #testForm="ngForm">

    <input 
        type="text" 
        name="testField" 
        ngModel #testField="ngModel" 
        [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': testField.errors && testForm.submitted}" 
        required>
        
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Required field
    </div>

    <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(testForm)">Submit</button>

</form>
```

In most of the cases the below code works and resets both values and submitted state.

**Normal reset :**

```js
onSubmit(form:NgForm) {
    // Other operations
    form.resetForm();
}
```

Sometimes the above code just replaces the values and the validations remain since the `submitted` state is still true. I've seen other people having the same issue and are using a hack which is to wrap the reset function inside a `settimeout()` with zero interval.

**Hack :**

```js
onSubmit(form:NgForm) {
    // Other operations
    setTimeout(() => {
        form.resetForm();
    }, 0);
}
```

This will do the job but I still don't understand why or how it works. Any thoughts on this behaviour?

Comment: Seems like a changeDetection issue. You can also use `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` rather than wrapping around setTimeout. Can we replicate it on stackblitz example ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ubqsrt?file=src/app/app.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ubqsrt?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Lucky that I could reproduce. Usually weird behaviors like these won't come anywhere near when we trying to fix it xD.